# Testing angular2 service having constructor with http dependency

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular

How to write jasmine test case for the following class having constructor which is having dependency on http

```ts
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';

@Injectable()
export class MockUserService {
    items:Array<any>;

    constructor(http:Http){
        http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080/src/data/names.json')
        .subscribe(res => {
            this.items = res;
            console.log('results found');
        })
    }
}
```

I tried in following way ,

```ts
 it('Testing user login', inject([MockUserService,Http], (mockUserService:MockUserService ) => {
   let http:Http;
        let mockUserService: MockUserService = new MockUserService(http);
     expect(1+1).toEqual(2);

  });
  );
```

I am getting DI error:
[DI error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwpRs.png)

Answer (score 1):

This test
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/test/http/http_spec.ts#L104
uses `return new Http(backend, defaultOptions);` where `backend` is a `MockBackend` (`import {MockBackend, MockConnection} from 'angular2/src/http/backends/mock_backend';`

Answer (score 1):

You can use beforeEachProviders to DI easily like below:

```
beforeEachProviders(() => [
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  MockUserService
]);

describe('MockUser Service', () => {
  it('Testing user login',
    inject([MockUserService], (service: MockUserService) => {
      expect(1 + 1).toEqual(2);
    }));
});
```

I hope this will help you(of at least 6 months ago).